# MySQL - Track user activity to display content only the first time

Tags: mysql

I need to show a modal window the first time the user logs in, after logging in, that modal window should not be displayed.

**Questions:**

I'm thinking of creating a field in the user table to be called, modal_first_time, and adding the values 0 or 1

0 = Modal not shown
1 = Modal shown

So that when you log in for the first time, perform a logging in that table and change the value from 0 to 1, so you do not show that modal window again.

But is this optimal? What if I have 10 modal windows, do I have to create 10 additional fields?

It is well the way to add a field in the table, or there is some more optimal and simple, the best would be a session variable but these when clearing Cookies or switching computers would show again.

Comment: My recommendation is to create a table that stores: (id, user_id, modal_id, accessed )  - so in the event that a user logs on your website and are presented with 4 modal windows, you will insert 4 records... the `modal_id` will be the unique identifier for each modal window respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making a "Modal accessed" table.

This table would hold 4 columns.

```
UID, UserID, ModalID, accessed
```

To find if the current status of a Modal for a user you would run a SELECT in your "onLogin" event.

Below is a very rough example of how this could be utilized to work for 1 or many Modals

```
SELECT ModalID FROM `SchemaName`.`ModalAccessedTable`
WHERE UserID = "Bob"
AND Accessed = 0
```

OR another usage

```
SELECT Accessed FROM `SchemaName`.`ModalAccessedTable`
WHERE UserID = "Bob"
AND ModalID = 'ModalName'
```

Update access usage

```
UPDATE `SchemaName`.`ModalAccessedTable` 
SET Accessed = 1 
WHERE UserID = "Bob"
AND ModalID = 'ModalName'
```

With a setup like this you can select, and update each individual entry per userID as needed, with relatively efficient lookup efficiency.

Side Note: 
Assuming this table will become large, you will benefit greatly from properly build multi-column indexes.

Comment: Thank you very much